# trying to convert binary to greycode

Tags: c, binary

I was trying to convert binary to greycode but I don't know what is wrong with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// I copied this function from wiki
unsigned int binaryToGray(unsigned int num) {
    return num ^ (num >> 1);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int binarynum = 10;
    unsigned num = binaryToGray(binarynum);
    printf("%d!!", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is the output you get for a specific input? do you get any errors?

Comment: This is **the** classic binary to grey code conversion function, what does it do that you do not expect? If the output does not appear, modify the `printf` to add a trailing line feed: `printf("%d!n", num);`

Comment: the input is 10, it should gives me a 11 in greycode but this code prints 15

Comment: 10 is decimal not binary! Try 2 (decimal for binary 10), it should outputs 3 (decimal for 11 binary).

Comment: thanks, you are right, this works

Answer (score 1):

In order to see how grey code works, add a function that converts a number to its binary representation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *numtobin(char *buf, unsigned int num) {
    char temp[65], *p = buf + sizeof(buf);

    *--p = '\0';
    while (num >= 2) {
        *--p = '0' + (num & 1);
        num >>= 1;
    }
    *--p = '0' + num;
    return strcpy(buf, temp);
}

// I copied this function from wiki
unsigned int binaryToGray(unsigned int num) {
    return num ^ (num >> 1);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char buf1[65], buf2[65];
    unsigned int num, greynum;

    for (num = 0, num <= 32; num++) {
        greynum = binaryToGray(num);
        printf("%2d  %6s -> %6s  %-2d\n",
               num, numtobin(buf1, num), numtobin(buf2, greynum), greynum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoshSu: can you please accept this answer if it fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

that should just work fine. Maybe add \n at the printf to have a linefeed in the result line.